# access redux state inside event listener not seeing latest value

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

In the below code, under useEffect hook, I am registering an event listener, which doesn't see the latest array values for "users" under the "subjects" redux store (subjects.users).

From stackoverflow, I got the suggestion to re-register on component re-render which I am thinking won't fit my scenario. Is there are other alternatives if you could suggest?

```
const HomeScreen = ({ route, navigation, subjects}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
    eventSource = new RNEventSource(environment.server_url + '/events?loginProvider=google', { headers: { 'authorization': `Bearer ${subjects.userToken}` } });
    eventSource.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        if (!event.data) { return; }
       
// redux state always has the initial state
        console.log(subjects.users)
        subjects.users.push(event.data)

    });
    },[]);

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {


    console.log("mapStateTOPROps ran", state)
    const { subjects } = state

    return { subjects }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators({
     logout, setUserId
    }, dispatch)
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

Comment: You are mixing hooks and class component concepts. As I can see in your snippet `HomeScreen` is functional component which uses `useEffect` so you cannot use `connect()`. You have to use `useSelector()` in order to get redux values with hooks/functional component

Comment: I am able to access the latest state in JSX template, only inside event listener code I am not able see the latest state.

Comment: As Ravi mentioned, I would not mix both concepts, if you are going down the react redux hooks path, use `useDispatch` and `useSelector`

Comment: Also, it is recommended not to mutate state, instead of `subjects.users.push`, try creating an action that appends `event.date` to the users

Comment: will remove connect and try to use your suggestion, thanks Ravi and alex

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty unsure how this happened since it hasn't happened to you before until now...

But I did resolved it using state directly from the store i.e.

```
import {store as myStore} from '../../../redux/createStore'; // this is the same store used in App.js <Provider store>

socket.addEventListener('message',async (e) => {
      console.warn(myStore.getState()); // this is giving u updated state

    });
```

Comment: I resolved this by using useDispatch and useSelector as mentioned in the question comments.